# Full Outer Join with Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by

**[UPDATED]: I have updated the question with the `WHERE` clause.**

I have the following SQL Fiddle. The result is:

```
|   User |          Name |   Time |
|--------|---------------|--------|
|  00001 |     Mary Jane |     12 |
|  00002 |   Joana Smith |      7 |
|  00003 |  George Andrz |      2 |
|  00004 | Julia Roberts |      4 |
```

I am expecting this:

```
|   User |          Name |   Time |
|--------|---------------|--------|
|  00001 |     Mary Jane |     12 |
|  00002 |   Joana Smith |      7 |
|  00003 |  George Andrz |      2 |
|  00004 | Julia Roberts |      4 |
|  90000 | Anderson Math |      0 |
|  90001 |      Josh Xin |      0 |
```

> The difference is: There are some users in the table MainUsers that
>   could not have done the TimeSheet yet, so the TimeSheet table is empty
>   for the person. But I would like to show the name, with the Time = 0

---

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26592/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MainUsers
(
  id int identity primary key, 
  UserID varchar(5), 
  FullName varchar(500),
);

INSERT INTO MainUsers
(UserID, FullName)
VALUES
('00001', 'Mary Jane'),
('00002', 'Joana Smith'),
('00003', 'George Andrz'),
('00004', 'Julia Roberts'),
('90000', 'Anderson Math'),
('90001', 'Josh Xin');

CREATE TABLE TimeSheet 
(
  id int identity primary key, 
  UserID varchar(5), 
  FullName varchar(500),
  Minutes int,
  TimeStamp Datetime,
);

INSERT INTO TimeSheet
(UserID, FullName, Minutes, TimeStamp)
VALUES
('00001', 'Mary Jane', 240, '2015-09-16 08:16:00'),
('00001', 'Mary Jane', 480, '2015-09-16 08:16:00'),
('00002', 'Joana Smith', 320, '2015-09-16 08:16:00'),
('00002', 'Joana Smith', 120, '2015-09-16 08:16:00'),
('00003', 'George Andrz', 120, '2015-09-16 08:16:00'),
('00004', 'Julia Roberts', 240, '2015-09-16 08:16:00');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT u.UserID AS [User], u.FullName AS Name,
       SUM(t.Minutes) / 60 AS [Time]
FROM MainUsers u LEFT JOIN
     TimeSheet t
     ON u.UserID = t.UserID
WHERE
    month(TimeStamp) = 9 and year(TimeStamp) = 2015
GROUP BY u.UserID, u.FullName
ORDER BY u.UserID ASC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26592/1/0)**:

```
|  User |          Name | Time |
|-------|---------------|------|
| 00001 |     Mary Jane |   12 |
| 00002 |   Joana Smith |    7 |
| 00003 |  George Andrz |    2 |
| 00004 | Julia Roberts |    4 |
```

Thanks.

Comment: why are you using a full outer join instead of a left join?

Comment: Because left join did not work too. I think Full Outer should work, but isn't neither.

Comment: no, you need to left outer join your main table (users) to your related table (timesheet).  To join in the sequence you have, timesheet -> users, you'd use a RIGHT outer join.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT
    u.UserID AS 'User',
    u.FullName AS Name,
    isnull(SUM(Minutes) / 60,0) AS [Time]
FROM
    MainUsers u left OUTER JOIN 
    TimeSheet t  ON 
    u.UserID = t.UserID
GROUP BY
    u.UserID,
    u.FullName
ORDER BY
    u.UserID
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8cfee/15)

if you want to include conditions on your timesheet table, such as 
`month(timestamp) = 9 and year(timestamp) = 2015`
and you do it in the `WHERE` clause, it converts your `outer join` to an `inner join` because the `WHERE` clause requires fields in the timestamp table.  To limit by month and year of your `left outer join`ed table, you put the conditions in the `JOIN` clause instead of `WHERE`, like:

```
SELECT
    u.UserID AS 'User',
    u.FullName AS Name,
    isnull(SUM(Minutes) / 60,0) AS [Time]
FROM
    MainUsers u left OUTER JOIN 
    TimeSheet t  ON 
    u.UserID = t.UserID and
    month(timestamp) = 9 and year(timestamp) = 2015
GROUP BY
    u.UserID,
    u.FullName
ORDER BY
    u.UserID
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26592/6)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `left join`.  Presumably, everyone with a timesheet is a valid user.  And you seem to want to keep all the users.

In general, when you use `full outer join` you have to be very careful about `NULL` values.  `COALESCE()` ends up being used extensively.  So, your query can be written as:

```
SELECT u.UserID AS [User], u.FullName AS Name,
       SUM(t.Minutes) / 60 AS [Time]
FROM MainUsers u LEFT JOIN
     TimeSheet t
     ON u.UserID = t.UserID
GROUP BY u.UserID, u.FullName
ORDER BY u.UserID ASC;
```

Also note that the query is much easier to follow when your table aliases are abbreviations for the table names. `A` and `B` don't mean anything.  But it is clear that `t` stands for `TimeSheet`.

Finally, the `time` column is probably hours as an integer -- assuming that `Minutes` is an integer. (And it would be better called something like "hours".)  If you want decimal hours, then divide by 60.0, rather than 60.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This helps me with some where conditions. I am trying to update the fiddle but isn't working. I have another column in the TimeSheet table, it is `TimeStamp`, a datetime column. When o put, for example: Where month(timestamp) = 9 and year(timestamp) = 2015 it does not shows the null values. Can you help in this case? Thanks.

Comment: @Khrys . . . Put the condition in the `ON` clause not a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change Join from FULL OUTER to RIGHT OUTER
2. Group by should be applied on userid and name of MainUsers table and not on TimeSheets
3. Select list should be accordingly modified.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8cfee/20)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
    B.UserID AS 'User',
    B.FullName AS Name,
    SUM(A.Minutes) / 60 AS [Time] 
FROM
    TimeSheet A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN MainUsers B ON A.UserID = B.UserID
GROUP BY
    B.UserID,
    B.FullName
ORDER BY
    B.UserID ASC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8cfee/20/0)**:

```
|  User |          Name |   Time |
|-------|---------------|--------|
| 00001 |     Mary Jane |     12 |
| 00002 |   Joana Smith |      7 |
| 00003 |  George Andrz |      2 |
| 00004 | Julia Roberts |      4 |
| 90000 | Anderson Math | (null) |
| 90001 |      Josh Xin | (null) |
```

I guess, This is what you are looking for.
Hope it might help you. :)